# how to add transition animation to this DIV TOGGLE Hid/Show ?

Tags: javascript, animation

I have this dive the toggle Hide / Show !! ... It works ok , but I would like to know how to add transition animation to the hide/show ?

this is my JS :

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("clock1");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none" ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate the `display` property. But you can animate the `visibility` or `opacity` property in css easily:

```
// main.html
<div id="clock1" class="hidden">...</div>

// main.css
#clock1 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
#clock1.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

// main.js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("clock1")
  if (x.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    x.classList.remove('hidden')
  } else {
    x.classList.add('hidden')
  }
}
```

Comment: this one works , but it starts it hidden by DEFAULT .. how do I start it shown and then hide on click ? and also ,, how do I then make the DIV minimize ? allowing that it will close, for the next DIV to shift  up ^  ?

Comment: forget the first parft . it works ... BUT ... how do I then make the DIV minimize ? allowing that it will close, for the next DIV to shift  up ^  ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display` to `none` will immediately hide the element, which means there is not opportunity for animation/transition of visibility over time.

Perhaps you could consider using `opacity` instead, to achieve this?

#### Add the following CSS:

```
#clock1 {
  transition:opacity 1s;
}
```

#### Update your JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("clock1");
  // Update opacity rather than display       
  if (x.style.opacity === "0") {
      x.style.opacity = 1; 
  } else {        
      x.style.opacity = 0;   
  }
}
```

Working [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnvj6ps/2/)

Comment: it works , but it takes 2 clicks to work , and it only HIDES ! doesn't work to SHOW back .. can u help ?

Comment: nope , now doesn't work at all .. the solution answered below worked for me .. but if u can help me fix the problem I commented on I'd be grateful , thanx

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý i just updated with a jsFiddle link showing it is working - does this work at your end?